# Can't install aptik package on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04

I'm trying to install `aptik` package to make a recovery from my Ubuntu applications. But after importing `ppa:teejee2008/ppa` repository and executing `sudo apt-get install`, it can't locate the package `aptik`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that the package can not be located in Ubuntu 15.04.
The package is present in the [repository](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=vivid) and has a Vivid Vervet version.

Please make sure you properly ran those three commands :

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Comment: Agreed, was just gonna say, did you `apt-get update`

Comment: Indeed, I think OP simply missed the `sudo apt-get update` :)

Answer (score 0):

As @hg8 mentioned you might have missed `sudo apt-get update`

You can also install `aptik` from [this](https://code.launchpad.net/~sonicwalker/+archive/ubuntu/sonicos/+index?field.series_filter=wily) repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sonicwalker/sonicos
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```